# Where to install gpsbabel so it works with GPS::Babel perl module?

Tags: perl-module, gpsbabel

I'm sad that I have to ask a question this simple but where should [gpsbabel](http://www.gpsbabel.org) be installed in order to work with the [GPS::Babel](http://search.cpan.org/~andya/GPS-Babel-0.11/lib/GPS/Babel.pm) perl module? I can't seem to figure out the appropriate path and am hoping someone else who has it working can help. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GPS::Babel Perl module uses File::Which to find the gpsbabel executable.

The script/program you're running that "use"'s GPS::Babel needs to be run by a user that, when File::Which::which() is called, can find the gpsbabel executable in that user's OS-dependent PATH environment variable.

For example, installing gpsbabel on Linux results in gpsbabel being installed at /usr/local/bin.   Since /usr/local/bin is in my path, when I invoke a Perl script use'ing GPS::Babel, File::Which::which finds gpsbabel in /usr/local/bin.

What OS? What's your PATH environment variable set to?  Are you sure the gpsbabel executable was installed correctly, ie, can you verify the directory/folder it's installed in?

I had no issues downloading/installing gpsbabel and GPS::Babel just now and writing a quick hello world Perl script to use GPS::Babel, on Linux.

Comment: @Mark - maybe I didn't install it correctly. I downloaded the GPSBabel for Linux ready to run version. What should I be doing after the download to successfully install it?

Comment: You should try running gpsbabel on the commandline to see if the executable was successfully installed and executes without error - basically, sanity check the install.

Comment: @Mark - which instructions did you use to install GPSBabel for Linux? On our machine it doesn't appear to be installed under /usr/local/bin.

Comment: I installed GPSBabel following instructions here http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.4.2/readme.html   Then. I installed GPS::Babel from CPAN, but I did have a few troubles there.  I have to update Module::Build first, then DateTime, then installing GPS::Babel picked up the rest of the prereqs ok (Geo::Gpx).   It wasn't entirely a straightforward process.  I tried installing just GPS::Babel, but saw numerous build errors and so quit cpan and started again between Module::Build and DateTime installs.  Good luck!

Comment: Quick follow up Mark. Did you build GPSBabel from source? If so, would you mind sharing the commands you used so I can see what I'm doing wrong. If you used one of the already compiled downloads, then how did you get it to install in /usr/bin which appears to be where the GPS::Babel perl module is looking for it? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I built GPSBabel from source.  Commands to install follow typical linux source dists.   ./configure && make && make install     Make sure you have libexpat installed, or linking will fail.  If File::Which is looking for it in /usr/bin, but gpsbabel is in /usr/local/bin then you have 2 options.  1) symlink /usr/local/bin/gpsbabel to /usr/bin/gpsbabel or 2) add /usr/local/bin to your path

Comment: One way to add /usr/local/bin in your path would be alter $ENV{PATH} in a BEGIN block prior to 'use GPSBabel'.  Like so:   BEGIN { $ENV{PATH} .= ':/usr/local/bin'}   then later, use GPS::Babel;